# less: how to match only those <li> with <ul> children

Tags: html, css, less, nested-lists

I have a nested list and want [less](/questions/tagged/less) to match only those `<li>` lines that have `<ul>` sub-lists.

For example in the following list I want to match `cats`, `devious` and `dogs`, but not `playful`, `destructive`, `deadly`, `fast` and `smart`.

```html
<ul>
<li>cats
  <ul>
  <li>playful</li>
  <li>devious
    <ul>
    <li>destructive</li>
    <li>deadly</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>dogs
  <ul>
  <li>fast</li>
  <li>smart</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible in CSS or LESS, but if you can use JQuery, then I would do it like this:

`$("li"):has("ul,li").addClass('childClass');`

Hope this helps!